# Can't Safely Remove USB, handle on MasterFileStatus.db

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

The "Safely Remove" function for USB drives does not work on my system. I always get the standard message:

> Problem Ejecting USB Mass Storage Device
>
> ---
>
> This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try
> again.

Trying to figure out the reasons, I found the following handles using the Process Explorer:

```
E:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$Txf
E:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLog.blf
E:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLog::KtmLog
E:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLogContainer00000000000000000001
E:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLogContainer00000000000000000002
E:\System Volume Information\MasterFileStatus.db
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyU06.png)

They all point to a process: System (PID: 4)

I checked on another computer (where Safely Remove works without problems) and there were also handles on `$Extend\$RmMetadata`, but not on `System Volume Information\MasterFileStatus.db`.

**Hence the question: what is this handle on `MasterFileStatus.db`, what is it for and how to remove this lock?**

My OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (22H2, Build 19045.2604)

- I already tried deleting the entire directory. It reappears with this
  lock.
- System Restore is not enabled for this drive. The problem
  appears when connecting any drive, not just one.
- I know that it is possible to remove drives without using safely remove. Safely remove is not the main goal.

The main purpose of the question is to understand the problem and find out if I have any hidden problems with the system, the symptom of which is the current problem.

Comment: The file MasterFileStatus.db may be part of Windows Backup. You can try turning off Backup: https://www.acronis.com/en-us/blog/posts/windows-backup/ . In any event, one should *never* modify *System Volume Information*. Doing so can corrupt the file system.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I didn't find any sign of Windows Backup enabled on my system. I checked services and scheduler. I also checked the services related to Acronis, they are also turned off.

Comment: I still haven't found the answer.
This file is referenced by many applications as if it were part of the system, but I couldn't find any mention of it